# SQL - Query for duplicate records against different database servers

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have two separate SQL servers, each hosting the same table. Essentially one of these is a 'slave' and the other a 'master'. The master calls the slave every 10 mins and pulls the records from the slave to the master then deletes the ones on the slave.

However, we now have a scenario whereby (due to a coding bug within the application), there are some records which exist on the Master AND the Slave, which is preventing the transfer of records from completing as the process bombs out with an exception error around duplicate entries.

What I'm trying to do is come up with a query which will display all records which are duplicates (ie exist on both servers) in order to then purge these from the Slave.

I've used the Registered Servers option in Management Studio to add the two servers to a single sql query. I've tested this by identifying a single record which exists on both DBs and using a Select statement I can find it, logic as follows;

```
SELECT [Reserved]
FROM   [sctracking].[dbo].[scTracking]
WHERE [Reserved] = 'WHATEVER_THE_VALUE_IS'
```

This returns two rows, something like

```
Servername - Reserved
Server1    - WHATEVER_THE_VALUE_IS
Server2    - WHATEVER_THE_VALUE_IS
```

What I was then 'trying' to do was use a count value to run across both DB's, something like;

```
SELECT [Reserved]
       , COUNT(1) as CNT
FROM [sctracking].[dbo].[scTracking]
GROUP BY [Reserved]
```

However the above logic clearly doesn't work.

Any help anyone could give me here would be very greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you have obfuscated too much.  You say you run a query that selects one column, and then you show us results that have 2 columns.   It's not clear what you're querying, or what result you're REALLY getting, and I don't feel like I understand your problem at all.   There are hundreds of questions on here about how to find duplicates, and I don't understand what's special about your case that none of those solutions can help you.

Comment: You can use EXCEPT to find data discrepancies between your tables on Master and Slave or INTERSECT to find data that exists on both Master and Slave.

Comment: Here is a completely different approach. Have you considered using synonyms? Typically trying to keep two copies of the exact same information if a bad idea. It goes against the concept of a single point of truth. Is there a reason you can't simply query the remote table when you need the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand you correctly, but assuming I do, when you link the servers, it's as easy as this:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB FROM ServerNameA.DatabaseA.dbo.TableA AS A
WHERE EXIST 
( SELECT * FROM ServerNameB.DatabaseB.dbo.TableB AS B
  WHERE A.ColA = B.ColA )
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Firstly, thanks for this, however I'm not quite there.

Servers are now linked. Below is my attempt at the code;

    SELECT [Reserved]
    FROM  [Server1\DB_Name].[sctracking].[dbo]. 
   [scTracking] AS A
    WHERE EXIST
    ( SELECT * FROM [Server2\DN_Name].[sctracking].[dbo]. 
   [scTracking] AS B
    WHERE A.Reserved = B.Reserved )

This produces the following error;

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Any thoughts?